# Why isn't the super class of a meta class of a root class a NULL pointer?

Tags: objective-c, class, objective-c-runtime

In the objective-c runtime, a class is represented by a structure like this:

```
typedef struct class_t {
    struct class_t *isa;    // Points to the class' meta class
    struct class_t *super;  // Points to the class' super class
    Cache cache;
    IMP *vtable;
    union {
        class_ro_t *rodata;
        class_rw_t *rwdata;
    };
} class_t;
```

When a `MyClass` class is a root class and not a meta class, its super member is a NULL pointer (which is understandable, since it is a root class, so it doesn't have a super class).
However, if we get the isa member of that same `MyClass` root class (which points to `MyClass`' meta class), and we get the super member of that isa member, it is not a NULL pointer, but a pointer to `MyClass` (not meta class). Shouldn't the super class of a meta class of a non-meta root class be a NULL pointer (as the super class of a non-meta root class is)? 
Since it's not, for what is it supposed not to be?

I'm asking this because, the way things are actually, if `methodX` is an instance method (not a class method) of a `MyClass` root class, the statement `[MyClass methodX]`
would call `methodX` (and it actually does), what shouldn't happen (again, because `methodX` is a instance method, not a class method, so it should not respond to the `[MyClass methodX]` statement).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Obective-C language specifically decided that class objects should respond to the instance methods of their root class. This is primarily a pragmatic decision; since NSObject is mostly responsible for handling the fundamentals of how ObjC interacts with objects, it would be annoying to have to implement everything twice; once for class objects and once for instances. Class objects can be put into arrays, etc. so they need to respond to `-retain` and `-release` just like instances do.

You can read more about it in the "Methods of the Root Class" section of this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html